# Why is my data not being submitted into the database

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to create adding/creating a new menu and saved it in the database. However, when I clicked the button, my system didn't show any error but the data is not saved in the database.

adminAddMenu.blade.php

```
<form>
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="categorycode" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Category Code</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input name="category_code" value="{{old('category_code')}}"  class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="menutitle" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Menu Title</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input name="menu_title" value="{{old('menu_title')}}" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="menuprice" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Menu Price</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <textarea name = "menu_price" value="{{old('menu_price')}}" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-9">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href="">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

AdminMenuController.php

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $menu = new \App\Menu;
    $menu->category_code = $request->category_code;
    $menu->menu_title = $request->menu_title;
    $menu->menu_price = $request->menu_price;

    $menu->save();
    
    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Menu is successful! added');

    return redirect()->back();
 }
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('/menus', 'AdminMenuController');
```

Comment: Try `dd($request->all())` above `$menu = new \App\Menu;`

Comment: Check this line `$requescategory_code->menu_image;`

Comment: `<input type="int" />` doesn't exist. There is `<input type="number" />` instead.

Comment: Do you have $fillable array in your \App\Menu? There is no menu_image input in adminAddMenu.blade.php.

Comment: tried dd($request->all()) but it gives me syntax error, unexpected '$menu' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: i have no $fillable array and i've corrected the menu_image already. Still getting the same thing

Comment: you have to add a semicolon in each line of php code. `dd($request->all());`. and why is your form does not have action and method attribute??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give the form action method where your data will submit. Like you want to send your form data to store method in your controller. So you have to write follow:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('your route name') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the action attribute of your form. Please add action to your form

```php
<form action="{{ YOUR_ROUTER }}">
...
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

Please add action on form tag.
Like as-

**<form action={{ route("your route write here") }} method="post">**

I think now it's work's.

Comment: There's no need to duplicate existing answers, unless you want to add some new insights